# ESXi 4: Access physical disk without creating datastore

Tags: vmware-esxi

Recently started experimenting with ESXi 4 on an older system.
(I know, v5 is out but I don't have the required hardware yet)

The system contains 3 physical disks:

```
Disk A: 250GB IDE containing ESXi and ISO files. Disk is set as datastore.
Disk B: 250GB SATA used for hosting VM disk images. Disk is set as datastore.
Disk C: 750GB SATA **not** set as datastore.
```

As `Disk C` still contains data that I would like to preserve I was wondering if it were possible to access this disk without making it into a datastore. As I recall, creating a datastore out of a disk will wipe the disk.

Comment: Yah, making a datastore requires a repartitioning and reformatting of the disk to `vmfs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Raw Device Mapping to have a VM on ESXi access the data on Disk C.  See: [About Raw Device Mapping](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.server_configclassic.doc_41/esx_server_config/raw_device_mapping/c_about_raw_device_mapping.html) @ VMware.com.  I don't think there's a way for you to access the data on Disk C from within ESXi without creating a VM.

Here's the relevant VMware KB article on how to map the disk: [Create RDM mappings](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/creating_virtual_machines/t_create_raw_device_mappings.html).

**Procedure**

1. Select a target LUN and click Next.
2. Select the datastore on which to store the LUN mapping file.
   -- Store with the virtual machine files
   -- Specify datastore
3. Click Next.
   -- The Select Compatibility Mode page opens.
4. Select a compatibility mode and click Next.
   -- Option
   --- Description
   ---- Physical
   ----- Allows the guest operating system to access the hardware directly. Taking a snapshot of this   virtual machine will not include this disk.
   ---- Virtual
   ----- Allows the virtual machine to use VMware snapshot and other advanced functionality.
5. Accept the default virtual device node or select a different node.
6. (Optional) Select the virtual disk Independent mode and select an
   option.
   -- Option
   --- Description
   ---- **Persistent**
   ----- The disk operates normally except that changes to the disk are permanent even if the virtual machine is reverted to a snapshot.
   ---- **Nonpersistent**
   ----- The disk appears to operate normally, but whenever the virtual machine is powered off or reverted to a snapshot, the content of the disk returns to its original state. All later changes are discarded.
   Independent disks are not affected by snapshots.
7. Click Next

Your changes are recorded and the Ready to Complete page opens.